# Cancel build request in buildbot 1.2.0

Tags: python, continuous-integration, buildbot

In order to use buildbot to trigger different actions (start, check, stop) and cancel build requests based on the status of an event (Implements the threading.Event interface based on a file) we were using the nextBuild property of buildbot.plugins.util.BuilderConfig (http://docs.buildbot.net/latest/manual/cfg-builders.html):

```
BuilderConfig(...,
              nextBuild=partial(handle_property_action_for_next_build, event))
```

So based on the action (start, stop, check) and the status of the event we would cancel all requests with cancelBuildRequest:

```
def handle_property_action_for_next_build(event, _, requests):
    action = requests[0].properties.getProperty("action")

    if action == "start":
        if event.is_set():
            for request in requests:
                request.cancelBuildRequest()
            return None
        else:
            event.set()
```

But the cancelBuildRequest method was removed some time ago: https://github.com/buildbot/buildbot/commit/95b90d7f0881dd4891199b16be9af2242729081b#diff-e55fd5266f5206f358b6da23011e41f0

So the question is how would I cancel a build request with buildbot 1.2.0?

It doesn't need to be in the nextBuild attribute but somewhere where I have:

1. Access to current action
2. Can pass the custom event
3. Can cancel the build request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using data api:

`request.master.data.control("cancel",
                              ("buildrequests", request.id))`